# Jooq enum converter uses the ordinal number. How can I switch to use the enum value number instead?

Tags: enums, jooq, jooq-codegen-maven

We have an Enum class with customized values. The values are different from their ordinals intentionally for business purpose which I cannot change.

```
enum class Role(val value: Int) {
  EXECUTOR(1),
  MONITOR(3),
  ADMIN(5),

  companion object {
    private val map = Role.values().associateBy(Role::value)
    fun fromInt(role: Int) = map[role]
  }
}
```

We are using JOOQ and postgres. We use the JOOQ default `EnumConverter` to convert db role integer values to objects.

```
ForcedType()
    .withUserType("com.company.enums.Role")
    .withEnumConverter(true)
    .withIncludeExpression("role"),
```

However we noticed a problem -- the database stored the ordinals of the enum, instead of the values. For example we see in the db in roles column, the db value is 1, and the translated Enum is MONITOR, coz MONITOR has an ordinal of 1.

How can we store the values of Enum into db using JOOQ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course implement a custom converter from scratch, as you [suggested in your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71066429/521799). But do note that starting from jOOQ 3.16 and https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12423, you can simplify that implementation by extending the `org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter` like this:

```kotlin
class RoleConverter : EnumConverter<Int, Role>(
  Int::class.java, 
  Role::class.java, 
  Role::value
)
```

Comment: Thank you! while i was looking at the implementation of `EnumConverter` I realized the author of jooq has came to answer this question! Honored :)

Answer (score 1):

Ohhh I figured it out! There's Custom Converter https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/ which is exactly what I need.